# python yaml openstack how to access element of one group

Tags: python, openstack

I have a yaml file like this:

```yaml
clouds:

 all:
  gr1:
   id: '202401'
  gr2:
   id: '202402'
  gr3:
   id: '202403'
  gr4:
   id: '202404'

 group1:
  gr1:
   id: '202401'

 group2:
  gr2:
   id: '202402'

 group34:
  gr3:
   id: '202403'
  gr4:
   id: '202404'
```

This is my Python code:

```
import openstack
import yaml

with open('test.yaml', 'r') as f:
    reg = yaml.safe_load(f)

all_groups = []
for name in reg['clouds']['all']:
    all_groups.append(name)

group1 = []
for name in reg['clouds']['group1']:
    group1.append(name)

group34 = []
for name in reg['clouds']['group34']:
    group34.append(name)

# Initialize and turn on debug logging
openstack.enable_logging(debug=False)

# Initialize connection
for region in all_groups:
    conn = openstack.connect(cloud=region) # test.yaml
```

This is the error:

```
openstack.exceptions.ConfigException: Cloud gr1 was not found.
```

The error is correct because I have no `clouds ==> gr1`, and it should be like `clouds ==> all ==> gr1`, but I'm not sure how.

I even tried this (I'm thinking of something like this but not sure the correct way):

```
# Initialize connection
for region in all_groups:
    conn = openstack.connect(cloud=['all'][region]) # test.yaml
```

But got this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I say in this context to access `clouds ==> all ==> gr1` for the mentioned module I'm using.

I download the yaml file from my website which is like this:

```yaml
clouds:

 gr1:
  id: '202401'
 gr2:
  id: '202402'
```

But I'm going to have file like in the beginning of the question.

Comment: I removed the YAML tag, as it is not relevant to this problem. You load a data structure (dicts, nested four levels), but you could create it from msgpack/JSON etc. ( I have no idea what openstack is, so I can't help you with the actual problem).

Comment: @Anthon thanks, it seems this is what's related to OpenStack software and I wait for them to see this question. As I'm seeing the original codes of the package, it doesn't do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a cloud name, the OpenStack python modules look for a configuration file named `clouds.yaml` in a [specific format](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/configuration/index.html#clouds-yaml). For this to work:

```
conn = openstack.connect(cloud='gr1')
```

You need to have a `clouds.yaml` file in either your current directory, in `~/.config/openstack`, or in `/etc/openstack`, and that file needs to have the necessary configuration information for connecting to cloud `gr1`. That might look something like:

```
clouds:
  gr1:
    auth:
      auth_url: http://192.168.122.10:35357/
      project_name: demo
      username: demo
      password: secret
    region_name: RegionOne
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I see there's no way because the module is not designed in this way. I did a workaround for this issue and it's working.